# Toast message popping up when page refreshes

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

This toast message pops up anytime I enter or refresh this page. What's triggering it please? I think it has something to with the loading states?
[image]

The toast message is coming from this Create Customer Button. The toast should only pop up when the user tries to create a customer without filling the required fields, but pops up whenever the page is refreshed or entered

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (!exchange && !currency && !currency_symbol) {
    toast({
      title: 'Incomplete form.',
      description: 'Please fill the required fields',
      status: 'error',
      position: 'top-right',
      duration: 3000,
      isClosable: true,
    })
  }
}, [exchange, currency, currency_symbol, customer])

useEffect(() => {
  if (isError) {
    toast({
      title: 'Something went wrong.',
      status: 'error',
      position: 'top-right',
      duration: 3000,
      isClosable: true,
    })
  }

  if (isSuccess) {
    toast({
      title: 'Customer created.',
      description: "Please refresh the table.",
      status: 'success',
      position: 'top-right',
      duration: 3000,
      isClosable: true,
    })
  }

  dispatch(reset());
}, [customer, isLoading, isError, isSuccess, message, dispatch]);
```

This is my customerSlice

```js
export const customerSlice = createSlice({
      name: "customer",
      initialState,
      reducers: {
        reset: (state) => {
          (state.isLoading = false),
          (state.isSuccess = false),
          (state.isError = false),
          (state.message = "");
        },
      },

      extraReducers: (builder) => {
          builder
            .addCase(createCustomer.pending, (state) => {
              state.isLoading = true;
              state.isError = false;
            })
            .addCase(createCustomer.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
              state.isLoading = false;
              state.isSuccess = true;
              state.customer.push(action.payload);
            })
            .addCase(createCustomer.rejected, (state, action) => {
              state.isLoading = false;
              state.isError = true;
              state.message = action.error.message;
            })

            .addCase(autoGenerate.pending, (state) => {
              state.isLoading = true;
            })
            .addCase(autoGenerate.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
              state.isLoading = false;
              state.isSuccess = true;
              state.customer = action.payload;
            })
            .addCase(autoGenerate.rejected, (state, action) => {
              state.isLoading = false;
              state.isError = true;
              state.message = action.error.message;
            })

            .addCase(getAllCustomers.pending, (state) => {
              state.isLoading = true;
              state.isError = false;
            })
            .addCase(getAllCustomers.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
              state.isLoading = false;
              state.isSuccess = false;
              state.customers = action.payload.payload.data;
            })
            .addCase(getAllCustomers.rejected, (state, action) => {
              state.isLoading = false;
              state.isError = true;
              state.message = action.error.message;
            })
```

Comment: Why is the toast called in a `useEffect`? Shouldn't it be called on a submission callback? Since when you load the component for the first time, obviously the form will probably be invalid and therefore trigger the toast.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhh @Undo